# Keeping name and score together while sorting

Tags: python, list, sorting, file-io

so I need to sort some high scores into order and here is the code I already have:

```
def sortscores():
    namelist = []
    scorelist = []
    hs = open("hst.txt", "r")
    hscounter = 0
    for line in hs:
        if counter%2 !=0:
            name = line
            othername = name[0:len(name)-1]
            namelist.append(othername)
        else:
            scorelist.append(int(line))
```

This puts the names and scores into lists so now I need to have them sorted but I can't use the .sort() function because I have to write the sort myself so can anyone tell me how I would do this? (sort the scores into descending order whilst keeping the names with the correct scores)

Comment: Why do you have to write the sort yourself? Is this homework?

Comment: Implement one of the many well-known [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Comment: @kindall Yeah, I've tried researching as much as I can myself and can't find how to do it in python and I asked my teacher and he said this counts as research

Comment: @RyanH2796 I would search around for "Sort python implementation." A lot of time, even WikiPedia will include a bit of code in Python for popular sorts. Please take note Python lists ARE ordered. Also, to keep them together, use a tuple or some other data structure: http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html

Comment: Hint: it may be useful to pair each name with its score in a tuple. You can use `zip` to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you store your high scores in `(name, score)` tuples, then you can easily keep them together. Since you need to write the sort function yourself, it might be helpful to look at an example of using tuples in another problem. Here's an example of simply finding the maximum  score while keeping the name and scores together.

First, set up the data. You can use `zip` for this

```
names = ['John', 'Jane', 'Tim', 'Sara']
scores = [100, 120, 80, 90]
data = list(zip(names, scores)) # For Python 2.X you don't need the 'list' constructor
print(data)
```

Outputs:

```
[('John', 100), ('Jane', 120), ('Tim', 80), ('Sara', 90)]
```

Now find the maximum entry:

```
max_entry = ('', 0)
for entry in data:
    if entry[1] > max_entry[1]:
        max_entry = entry

print(max_entry)
```

Outputs:

```
('Jane', 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could make a copy of your dict, find the biggest value, save the key to a list, remove the key from the dict and then do that again until the copied dict is empty.

```
import copy

scores = {'hawks': 23, 'eagles': 42, 'knights': 33, 'rabbits': 44} #this or read from .txt
scorescopy = copy.deepcopy(scores) #makes a copy of the dict, so you don't change the dict when deleting keys from the copy
rank = [] #the list in which we want the keys ranked by value

def keywithmaxval(scores): #finde the key with the highest value (stolen from another stackoverflow question)
     values = list(scores.values())
     keys = list(scores.keys())
     return keys[values.index(max(values))]

while len(scorescopy) > 0: #repeats until copy of dict is empty
    maxkey = keywithmaxval(scorescopy)
    scorescopy.pop(maxkey) #deletes key from copy of dict
    rank.append(maxkey) #puts key in the ranked list

print 'rank', rank #list of keys ranked by value
print 'copy of dict', scorescopy #copy of dict, should be empty after we looped trough
print 'original dict',scores #original dict, should be unchanged

print '\nRank:'
for key in rank: print key,':',scores[key] #pretty list of keys and vals
```