# Convert nested list to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested

I am new to python and learning about nested list and dictionaries. I am currently working on an assignment where I need to convert a list with student grades to a dictionary, where grades are integers:

```
student_grades = [
    ['Student', 'Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3'],
    ['Jane', '100', '90', '80'], 
    ['John', '88', '99', '111'],
    ['David', '45', '56', '67']
]
```

The output should look like this:

{['Jane'] : [100, 90, 80],['John'] : [88, 99, 11],['David'] : '45', '56', '67']}

I am not sure how to convert multiple nested list to a dictionary. Appreciate if anyone can point me in a right direction.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far and where you're stuck?

Comment: btw, I think the output should look like: `{'Jane': [100, 90, 80], 'John': [88, 99, 111], 'David': ['45', '56', '67']}`. Hint: look at dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Yes, Thant's right. Thank you.

Comment: @Paolo Ha, I just mentioned that in my answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keeping name and score together while sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859834/keeping-name-and-score-together-while-sorting)

Comment: Another possible duplicate you might want to check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014444/reading-input-files-and-writing-into-output-files-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionary keys can't be lists †. You probably want strings, not lists with one element.

I.e. `'Jane'` instead of `['Jane']`.

---

You can use a dictionary-comprehension; iterating from the second sub-list onward. We also use a list-comprehension to convert the grades to integers.

```
{name:[int(score) for score in scores] for name,*scores in student_grades[1:]}
```

which gives:

```
{
  "Jane": [
    100,
    90,
    80
  ],
  "John": [
    88,
    99,
    111
  ],
  "David": [
    45,
    56,
    67
  ]
}
```

---

† The reason you can't have lists as keys for dictionaries because they are not *hashable*. A dictionary is essentially a hash-table that stores elements at memory locations related to their hashes so that you can "lookup" an element in a dictionary quickly. However, this only works if each key *can be* hashed, which a list can't. Why can't it? Because a hash should take into account all the constituent element of an object and should not change. However the elements of a list can change because it is a mutable data structure (in contrast to an immutable string or tuple etc.) hence it cannot reliably compute the same hash, so does not/can't implement the functionality.

Comment: you "suggest" that because in fact dictionary keys *can't* be lists (unhashable)

Comment: @Paolo didn't even consider the "no mutable keys" definitive aspect, thanks!

Comment: mind to add an explanation of why, in your answer? :)

Comment: @Paolo Sure thing.

Comment: @Joe the OP also looks like they want conversion to `int`s... :)

Comment: You can also make use of extended unpacking in 3.x and give some explicit names to make it as clear as possible, eg: `{name: [int(score) for score in scores] for name, *scores in student_grades[1:]}`

Comment: @JonClements Nice. I knew in the back of my mind that there was *a way* to do this kind of unpacking where not element is assigned a variable, but I couldn't recall it.

Comment: gosh the OP asks ints for jane/john and strings for david XD. anyway I don't think it's wise to bother

Comment: @JoeIddon  Thank you very much! Do you mind explaining why you used * in front of the scores?

Comment: When we write something like `... for a,b in ...` we are unpacking a list of length 2 into a and b. If the list is longer than 2 we get an error. However, if we want `a` to be the first element and `b` to be a list of all the other elements, we can use the special star syntax which does exactly that.

Comment: @Joe technically... *If the list is longer than 2 we get an error* - isn't correct - any iterable can be unpacked, and needs to match the requirements on the left hand side... so basically, it *needs* to be 2 elements that can be unpacked, no more, no less... anything else is an exception.

Comment: @JonClements Longer than, or less than, 2 is what I meant of course :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#Convert digits in string to numbers.
student_grades_int = [[int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in myList] for myList in student_grades]
student_grades_int = student_grades_int[1:]

#Using list comprehensions to create the structure.
student_grades_final = {[x for x in myList if isinstance(x, str)][0]:[x for x in myList if isinstance(x, int)] for myList in student_grades_int}
student_grades_final
     {'David': [45, 56, 67], 'Jane': [100, 90, 80], 'John': [88, 99, 111]}
```